# Constrain the height of multiple scrolling flex elements

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

When a flex container with multiple scrolling children overflows, the children share the height of the container in proportion to the natural heights of their content (left code example). However, this can get extreme when the height of one child is significantly larger than the height of the other (right code example). The smaller child becomes essentially invisible, or at least comically small. One way around this would be to set a `min-height` on each of the children, but that would waste space in cases where the children didn't have enough content to fill the minimum height.

What I want to be able to do is to ensure that a given child has a minimum height *if* it has enough content to fill it. To clarify, here are some additional examples, assuming an overall container height of 1000px and desired "minimum height with content" of 200px. On the left are the natural heights of the boxes and on the right are the desired heights inside the flex container.

```
// Total height is smaller than container; no issues
700, 200       =>  700, 200
500, 500       =>  500, 500

// Smaller child's content is less than minimum height;
// bigger child should fill the space
1000, 50       =>  950, 50
6000, 100      =>  900, 100

// Proportional scaling does not violate minimum height
7000, 3000     =>  700, 300
8000, 2000     =>  800, 200

// Proportional scaling *does* violate minimum height
9000, 1000     =>  800, 200
1000000, 1000  =>  800, 200
```

(Note that the smaller child in these examples is always the second one, but this should work in any order with any number of children.)

```css
#box-a {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 8em;
}

#box-b {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  font-size: 4em;
}

#box-c {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 15em;
}

#box-d {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scrolling {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:600px; display:flex; justify-content: space-between">
    <div class="content container">
      <div class="header">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="box-a" class="container">
          <div class="scrolling">Box A</div>
        </div>
        <div id="box-b" class="container">
          <div class="scrolling">Box B</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content container">
      <div class="header">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="box-c" class="container">
          <div class="scrolling">Box C</div>
        </div>
        <div id="box-d" class="container">
          <div class="scrolling">Box D</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible with Flexbox, or CSS in general.

The reason is that CSS is not a programming language, and doesn't have any methods one can use to make those kind of calculations.

---

What is possible, using Flexbox, is to elaborate with its *flex-shrink* value, which with one control how a flex item share the remaining space, and in this case, a negative one.

Here I used each item's font-size's value (which in this case defines the height of the item) also for the *flex-shrink*, to show a possible end result.

What it does is simply, after each items content is subtracted, share the negative space like this, in e.g. the right column (and 18 is the sum of all items *flex-shrink* value):

- `c` gets 4/18
- `d` gets 12/18
- `e` gets 2/18

---

These values can either be calculated server-side and assigned inline, or client-side using a script.

If this is not an option, a script will be needed to adjust each items *minimum height*

---

Stack snippet

```css
#box-a {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 8em;
  flex: 0 8 auto;
}

#box-b {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  font-size: 4em;
  flex: 0 4 auto;
}

#box-c {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 4em;
  flex: 0 4 auto;
}

#box-d {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  font-size: 12em;
  flex: 0 12 auto;
}

#box-e {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 2em;
  flex: 0 2 auto;
}

.content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scrolling {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:500px; display:flex; justify-content: space-between">
    <div class="content container">
      <div class="header">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="box-a" class="container">
          <div class="scrolling">Box A</div>
        </div>
        <div id="box-b" class="container">
          <div class="scrolling">Box B</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content container">
      <div class="header">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="box-c" class="container">
          <div class="scrolling">Box C</div>
        </div>
        <div id="box-d" class="container">
          <div class="scrolling">Box D</div>
        </div>
        <div id="box-e" class="container">
          <div class="scrolling">Box C</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```